# SVG should not be cropped in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I have an SVG that looks correct when viewing in a simple webpage. However, the same SVG  is unexpectedly cropped when used to set a div's inner html in a React app.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14">  <defs>    <clipPath id="clip-path">      <rect id="Rectangle_709" data-name="Rectangle 709" width="14" height="14" fill="#0000ff"/>    </clipPath>  </defs>  <g id="Group_2312" data-name="Group 2312" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">    <path id="Path_2392" data-name="Path 2392" d="M3.178,10.859h7.645a.424.424,0,0,0,.4-.232.4.4,0,0,0-.036-.458L9.134,7.354a.456.456,0,0,0-.372-.182.423.423,0,0,0-.354.163L6.374,9.969,5.048,8.153a.436.436,0,0,0-.708,0L2.833,10.169a.455.455,0,0,0-.041.458.385.385,0,0,0,.386.232M1.707,14A1.645,1.645,0,0,1,.5,13.5,1.645,1.645,0,0,1,0,12.293V1.725A1.672,1.672,0,0,1,.5.5,1.637,1.637,0,0,1,1.707,0H12.275A1.664,1.664,0,0,1,13.5.5,1.664,1.664,0,0,1,14,1.725V12.293a1.637,1.637,0,0,1-.5,1.208,1.672,1.672,0,0,1-1.221.5Z" transform="translate(0 0)" fill="#0000ff"/>  </g></svg>
```

[image]
svg

[image]
cropped svg

I tried to disable practically all css in devtools to eliminate the cropping but I cannot find the issue.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: image.svg }}>
```

Any ideas what to look for?

Comment: svgs display better with inline elements like p tags.